# How to reduce the mic sensitivity in Android?

Tags: android

I was using MediaRecord's getMaxAmplitude() function to get the Amplitude.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude%28%29)

However, I find that it is quite sensitivity. That means a little voice will cause a great number of amplitude and reaching the maximum value 32767. Is any brother have idea about that?